# How can I campare two values in a ng-switch?

Tags: angularjs, switch-statement, compare, partials

I am unable to do this thing, getting a lot of errors how can I check ng-switch containing the value is not null and the in ng-switch-when compare two values and the load the partials.

View file

```
<div ng-switch="{{snl}} !='' ">
                <div ng-switch-when="{{sln}}=='admincat' " ng-include src="'/eve/public_html/partials/admincat.html'"></div> 
                <div ng-switch-default ng-include src="'/eve/public_html/partials/adminuser.html'"></div> 
            </div>
```

Controllers

```
$scope.grFunc = function (sidebar) {
            $scope.sln = sidebar;
            console.log($scope.sln);

        };
```

Comment: why dont u use ng-if if ng-switch has some problem

Comment: I can but the main purpose of posting this question is "how to check the condition ". I am unable to make the condition, I am a newbie, dont know much about angularjs

Comment: ng-switch when="({{sln}} == 'admincat')"---can we do like this????i am just guessing

Answer (score 1):

```
<div ng-if="snl">
  <div ng-switch="snl">
    <div ng-switch-when="admincat">test</div> 
    <div ng-switch-default>test2</div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lteftb0s/
Change the ng-init to test!

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
<div class="content" ng-switch on="snl">
    <div ng-switch-when="admincat">
         <div ng-include="'template1.html'"></div>
    </div>
    <div ng-switch-default>
         <div ng-include="'template2.html'"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```